# Ways to apply multiple classes which take more that one line in Pug without attribute duplicating

Tags: pug

I want to use ["disallowDuplicateAttributes" rule](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint/blob/master/docs/rules.md#disallowclassattributewithstaticvalue-true) from [pug-lint](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint) which, obviously, disallow attribute duplicates. Basically, attribute duplicating requires when we need to apply multiple long class names like:

```
td(
  class="ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ProductsTableHeaderDecoration"
  class="ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnSizer"
  class="ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnDecoration"
)
```

Which other methods are possible?

### Disallowed solution

1. Chain all classes into single line with class literal, because it impacts the maintainability. Also, I'm going to limit the columns count per line with same pug-lint.

```
td.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ProductsTableHeaderDecoration.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnSizer.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnDecoration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array of classes could be specified via [attributes literal](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attributes). Extra long classes could be split by string contacentation:

```
td&attributes({
  class: [
    "ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ProductsTableHeaderDecoration",
    "ProductsManagementPage-" + 
            "ProductsTable-ID_ColumnSizer",
    "ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnDecoration"
  ]
}) 有
```

Answer (score 0):

Chain the classes like this:

```
td.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ProductsTableHeaderDecoration.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnSizer.ProductsManagementPage-ProductsTable-ID_ColumnDecoration
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry about had not told about this solution is not allowed. I updated my question with reason why.